# Фильтр DataFrame по строкам и числам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли в pandas из DataFrame запросить данные по фильтру из колонок , в которых значения добавлены в виде str и int

Пример на скорую руку:

```
# Создаю Датафрейм
df = pd.DataFrame({'BMW X5': [],
               'BMW X6': [],
               'BMW 3': []})

bmw3 = 3.0

# В Датафрейм добавляю значения
df.loc[1, 'BMW X5'] = ('red')
df.loc[1, 'BMW X6'] = ('green')
df.loc[1, 'BMW 3'] = ('black | {}'.format(bmw3))
df.loc[2, 'BMW X5'] = (3.0)
df.loc[2, 'BMW X6'] = (4.4)
df.loc[2, 'BMW 3'] = ('black | {}'.format(bmw3))

# Из Датафрейма запрашиваю данные
df2 = df[['BMW X5']]

# Создаю новый Датафрейм с запрошенными данными
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df2)

# Пытаюсь получить данные по фильтру
choose = new_df[new_df['BMW X5'] == 'red']

print(choose)
print(df)
```

в примере я получил данные по фильтру

```
choose = new_df[new_df['BMW X5'] == 'red']
```

А если скажем в колонке 'BMW 3'
в 1 и 2 индексе, имеются строковые и числовые данные, как я могу и (возможно ли вообще ) отфильтровать ее.
Скажем так :

```
choose = new_df[new_df['BMW 3'] == 'black']
choose = new_df[new_df['BMW 3'] == 3.0]
```

спасибо большое за разъяснение!

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом `.isin`:

```
choose = new_df[new_df['BMW X5'].isin(['red', 3.])]
```

```
  BMW X5
1    red
2    3.0
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, ну по-моему это не совсем то , что мне нужно. Вот тут в примере https://prnt.sc/VpR77-X-gk17, имеется колонка BMW 3, как мне получить индексы этой колонки, скажем только те , где есть 'red' или же только те , где есть 2.0 ? Это возможно?

Comment: Возможно. `choose1=new_df.loc[new_df["BMW X5"] == 3]`, например. `choose1=new_df.loc[new_df["BMW X5"] == 3].index.to_list()` даст список индексов, где результат запроса удовлетворяет условию

Comment: к сожалению и это не сработало. Тут видимо 2 варианта, отдельно создавать колонку с текстом и отдельно с числами. Не подскажете , в pandas можно в одной колонке разместить 2 подстроки? на примере такого https://prnt.sc/Egf6oIfE6snc

Comment: вероятно, мы друг друга не понимаем. лучше, если вы приведете часть реального датафрейма в вопросе. что касается размещения подстрок в одной колонке, то это будут две _разные_ колонки, объединенные мультииндексом. в общем, смотрите про pandas Multiindex